# Finding the CDF of an exponential pdf

Tags: probability-theory

I have a past exam paper with no solutions. Lots of the questions give a PDF and want me to find a different PDF or CDF. I am a bit confused about how to find a CDF of a transformed variable and my books and notes dont cover this. One example is
for 
$f_x(x)= \lambda e ^{-\lambda x}$, $x>0$

find the CDF of $Z= 1 - X$

So, i have $P(Z<z)=P(1-X<z)=P(X>1-z)=1-P(X<1-z)$

however, i do not know where to go from here! I know i have to differentiate somewhere but not entirely sure what i do with $1-P(X<1-z)$, if that is even correct. I have an exam on this tomorrow and having a paper with no solutions is making me struggle with a few bits so please could you explain what you have done so that i can understand the topic.. Any help much appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: I would first find $f_{Z}(x)$ and then compute $P(Z<z)=\int_{-\infty}^{z}f_{Z}(x)dx$

Comment: how do i compute $f_z(x)$ though?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the cdf of your exponential is

$$\int_0^x \lambda e^{-\lambda t} dt = 1 - e^{-\lambda x},$$

for $x>0$.

Thus,

$$1-P(X<1-z) = \begin{cases} e^{\lambda(z-1)}, & z<1, \\ 1, & z>1.\end{cases}$$

Comment: thank you so much! how did you get the CDF as that? sorry i only learnt this recently!

Comment: The relationship between the pdf and cdf is $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt$.  In your case $f(t)=0$ for $t\leq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I just proved this yesterday using poisson distribution. Because if an event come as poisson distribution, the inter-arrival time would be exponential time. I use t1 to denote 
small amount of time, and T1 as random variable; then P (T1t1)
;then we need to find probability that inter-arrival time is larger then t1. If all inter-arrival time are larger than t1. we know that the probability that an event happen at t1 is 
zero,then we use the poisson distribution F(lambda* t1) = zero. to get CDF

pdf is the derivative of PDF [image]

Comment: it should be (lambda* t1) ^ 0, but not lambda*t1^0